# jQuery - How to auto load content every one minute using load()

Tags: jquery, load

I have a script that loads content using load() via a click function.

I'd like to change this to auto load content every one minute like a slideshow.

I have 3 videos I need to loop through.

Please can someone point me in the right direction I have no idea where to start. My current script is below.

Thanks

**I have updated the code below, in accordance with elliot-bonneville answer. I still need to find a way to loop through these videos.**

**JS**

```
// define var video
var video = $('div.video');
var linkOne = $('.video_1').attr('href');
var linkTwo = $('.video_2').attr('href');
var linkThree = $('.video_3').attr('href');

setInterval(function() {
// load content into video
video.load( linkTwo + ' .content' , function() {
    // remove loading text
    $('.load').remove();
});
}, 10000) // 60000 milliseconds = one minute

setInterval(function() {
// load content into video
video.load( linkThree + ' .content' , function() {
    // remove loading text
    $('.load').remove();
});
}, 10000) // 60000 milliseconds = one minute

setInterval(function() {
// load content into video
video.load( linkOne + ' .content' , function() {
    // remove loading text
    $('.load').remove();
});
}, 10000) // 60000 milliseconds = one minute
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `setTimeout`

I think something like the below. I haven't tested it yet, so there might be some syntax errors. But hopefully you understand. let me know if anything doesn't make sense.

One reason I am using `setTimeout` rather `setInterval` is that this way, another timer doesn't get fired until after the load has completed. In this case, it won't matter too much as you are only doing it every 1 minute, but in some cases, the server latency might be more then the interval time. Also, this way, if for whatever reason, the script/server goes down and a successful reply isn't received then another call won't be made.

```
// define var video
var video = $('div.video');
var currentVid=1;
var maxVid=3;

setTimeout(cycleVideo, 10000) // 60000 milliseconds = one minute

function cycleVideo() {
    // load content into video
    var link = $('.video_'+currentVid).attr('href');
    video.load( link + ' .content' , function() {
        // remove loading text
        $('.load').remove();
        if(currentVid==maxVid) currentVid=1; else currentVid++;
        setTimeout(cycleVideo, , 10000) // 60000 milliseconds = one minute

    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks you are a genius, your code was awesome but there was an extra comma after cycleVideo that stumped me for a bit. Cheers

Comment: Thanks for that. Code all fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

Use `setInterval`, like this:

```
setInterval(function() {
    var link = $('#yourAElementId').attr('href');

    // load content into video
    video.load( link + ' .content' , function() {
        // remove loading text
        $('.load').remove();
    });
}, 60000); // 60000 milliseconds = one minute
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I forgot to add that I have 3 videos that I need to loop through. Any ideas how to incorporate this? Thanks

Comment: @ClintonGreen you should probably edit your question with that extra requirement :)